# ManagementObject leaking in C# COM DLL

Tags: c#, c++, com, memory-leaks, wmi

I have a C# COM DLL that calls WMI using the `System.Management` namespace. The DLL is being loaded into a C++ service. Every time I call the into the WMI classes I'm seeing a HUGE memory leak. After about an hour I am well over 1 GB of memory used.

If I take the same COM DLL and load it into PowerShell using `Reflection.LoadFrom` it does not leak memory. I have modified the DLL like so and it no longer leaks (still loading into the service with COM):

```
public class MyComObject
{
    public void CallCom()
    {
        CallSomeWMIStuff();
    }
}
```

To this. This no longer leaks!

```
public class MyComObject
{
    public void CallCom()
    {
        //CallSomeWMIStuff();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of some of the WMI code:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope( "root\\cimv2" );
scope.Connect();

using (var myservice = GetService("SomeService", scope))
{
    //Some Stuff
}
...
ManagementObject GetService(string serviceName, MangementScope scope)
{
            ManagementPath wmiPath = new ManagementPath( serviceName );

            using (ManagementClass serviceClass = new ManagementClass( scope, wmiPath, null ))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection services = serviceClass.GetInstances())
                {
                    ManagementObject serviceObject = null;

                    // If this service class does not have an instance, create one.
                    if (services.Count == 0)
                    {
                        serviceObject = serviceClass.CreateInstance();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject service in services)
                        {
                            serviceObject = service;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return serviceObject;
                }
            }
}
```

EDIT: C++ Snippet:

```
NAMESPACE::ICSharpComPtr pCSharpCom = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pCSharpCom .CreateInstance(NAMESPACE::CLSID_CSharpCom);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Log("Failed (hr=%08x)", hr);
    return hr;
}

try 
{
    _bstr_t bstrData = pCSharpCom ->GetData();

    strLine = (LPCTSTR)bstrData;
    strMessage += strLine;
}
catch (_com_error& err)
{
        _bstr_t desc = GetErrorMessage(err);
        Log("Excepton %S", (const wchar_t*)desc);
        return 0;
}

pCSharpCom ->Release();
```

Has anyone seen anything like this? We are seeing a similar issue with C++\CLI that's loading a different WMI related DLL directly.

Eventually, the WMI service will no longer be responsive and I will have to restart that service as well.

Edit:

This has to do with the apartment state of the COM object. Added a `CoInitializeEx` rather than a `CoInitialize`. I set the thread to MTA. At first it didn't look like this was working until I realized that first time the method was called we were seeing the thread state set to STA rather than MTA! Every subsequent call would be MTA. If I returned right away, before calling the `System.Management` classes when the thread was STA, I would no longer leak memory!

Any idea why the first one would be STA?

Comment: This happens when the garbage collector doesn't run, the RCWs don't get cleaned up.  You probably just don't generate enough garbage.  Check this with perfmon.exe.  GC.Collect is the workaround.

Comment: I tried this as well. It didn't seem to help.

Comment: After some further investigation GC.Collect is not helping the situation. It's still growing in memory and handles.

Comment: How is the C++ ICSharpComPtr type being generated? Also caputure the return value from the release call. If its a value > 0 then that would indicate there is another reference to the COM object. The returned bstrData strted out as a managed type, if its references are not being cleaned up correctly that could cause your entire .Net Com object to never be collected. However, its a string here so I think it would be martialed as a copy and not a direct reference to managed memory.

Comment: I didn't generate it but there is a TLB for the COM DLL. I'm assuming regasm or through the build. The Release is returning 0.  I've also now noticed that threads are stacking up...

Comment: OK, I really feel like it has something to do with what is being retruned from the managed .Net into the unmaaged C++. Is the GetData method the actual method you are calling, or is that just a representative example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the apartment state of the thread creating the COM object. There was one thread that created the COM object as MTA and another thread that was creating the COM object as STA. The STA thread was created first and then led to issues with the MTA threads. This caused the finalizer to block on GetToSTA.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a dispose in the RCW implementation so you are at the mercy of the GC to release the com objects you have created by default. However, you can try using [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) on the RCW instance once you are done with your COM objects. The will force the ref count to zero on the wrapped COM object and it should release. However, this also makes the RCW instance useless so be careful where you call it.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I'm forcing a GC.Collect every time and it seems to be working but it seems really heavy.

Comment: Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject does not work on the System.Management classes. :|

Comment: Does not work as in it throws an exception, or it does not release the memory ?

Comment: Sorry, throws an exception stating that objects need to derive fro __ComObject.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstadning on my part. I though you were using a RCW for the WMI. I see now that you are using the System.Management namespace which does implement dispose and you are calling it. I suspect now it may be the C++ code, can you post the C++ snipits you are using to create and call your .Net com object.